gb4e — refer to the next example
It is extremely annoying to add a \label to every gb4e example every time you want to refer to it in the preceding paragraph. linguex has \Next and expex has nextx for this, which refer to the next example without requiring you to label it:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}

(\nextx) is an \texttt{expex} example.

\ex
    an expex example.
\xe

\end{document}


\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\Next is a \texttt{linguex} example.

\ex. a linguex example.

\end{document}

This is such a common use case (relative to the field) that I'm surprised I couldn't find something similar for gb4e. Maybe someone knows a way to do this?

Welcome. // Why don't you absorb these by one or two \newcommand macros?

Personally, I prefer to add explicit labels, but it's not too hard to add this functionality to gb4e. Since this might be useful to others, I've created a small package gb4e-next which implements both a \Next and a \Prev command.
The gb4e package doesn't automatically use roman numerals for examples in footnotes, but instead expects you to use {xlisti} rather than {exe} if you want a roman numbered example. Since roman examples are quite common in footnotes generally, I've made a package option to specify the format of the example reference inside a footnote. To use \roman by default, load the package with:
\usepackage[fn=roman]{gb4e-next}

If for some reason you need to explicitly change the format of the referred example any other time, you can simply add the relative format as an optional argument to the \Next or \Prev commands:
\Next[arabic] % will format using \arabic
\Prev[alph]   % will format using \alph

The package is available on CTAN here but unless you're in a huge hurry, I would wait until it appears in current distribution updates in the next couple of days.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage[fn=roman]{gb4e-next}
\begin{document}
This is the reference to  example \Next.
\begin{exe}
\ex An example
\end{exe}

This is reference to example \Next.

\begin{exe}
\ex Another example
\end{exe}
This contains a footnote\footnote{This is a footnote with an example. We can refer to it as \Next. \begin{xlisti}\ex A footnote example\end{xlisti}} And this is a reference to the previous example: \Prev
\end{document}




this is awesome, thank you!

It turns out there was already a package that does the same thing: nnext. Supports either linguex or ExPex commands, but doesn't work inside footnotes.
